# Javascript function breaking/variables being forgotten

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's hard to describe the issue within the title, but basically, I have a function that, when a button is clicked, checks a bunch of attributes on the element in order to display/hide associated content.

It all works great, except when I tried to add an extra feature that hides a panel when a certain tab is selected. It's a simple if statement I thought I'd have no trouble with, but it has the strangest reaction I've ever seen.

There are 3 main tabs, and one of those tabs with a value of 'mirror' closes a group of tabs relating to patterns for a controller designer I am working on. When 'mirror' is clicked, the variable 'dependingvar' is set fine, however - it will only be used once. Here is the code of the if statement:

```
if (dependingvar !== undefined) {
jQuery('.' + dependingvar).children('.cdesign-toggle').first().trigger('click');
jQuery('.' + dependingvar).hide();
lastdepend = dependingvar;
} else {
jQuery('.' + lastdepend).show();
}
```

Only the very first line that triggers a click will run. The second one that hides the group does not run. If I swap these around, the block will hide, but the trigger wont run. I've checked the debug console, and the variable is literally getting unassigned as soon as it's ran the first one. I have no idea what is happening with it.

Here is the full code:
http://pastebin.com/6QncXf6c

I can't really do a JSFiddle due to the dependancies, but here's the HTML as a pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/nePQbtjE

I really just have no idea why this is happening. An important note, as well:
If the if statement is placed anywhere apart from the bottom, it breaks the rest of the code, unsetting variables, but ONLY if the condition is met (dependingvar !== undefined).

I'm hoping it's a stupid mistake, but can anyone spot it?

Comment: General note: You can reduce your jQuery code "a lot" with `$` instead of `jQuery` by using this shortcut DOM ready handler: `jQuery(function($){...all your code...});` It provides a locally scoped `$` as well as being a DOM ready handler :)

Comment: Alright, thanks. Out of interest, does that affect the scope of variables?

Comment: I see you have a fix for the actual bug. Here is an example of the code reduction I mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kkgmhrn6/ (no fixes applied)

Comment: I'm now utilizing this, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only quickly skimmed over your code, but a few things springs to mind:

`.trigger('click')` is run asynchronously. The event handler will set it to `undefined` (use `null` or something else by the way - `undefined` should only be used for undefined variables) .

In the very next line, you are referencing `dependingvar` again, but depending on whether or not the `.cdesign-toggle` `click` event has run to end, `dependingvar` may have one value or another. Instead of referencing `dependingvar` directly, try cloning it, so you know its value won't change inside your `if` statement, something along the lines of:

```
if (dependingvar !== undefined) {
  var dependingvar_ = dependingvar; // or jQuery.clone(dependingvar) depending on the type of dependingvar
  jQuery('.' + dependingvar_).children('.cdesign-toggle').first().trigger('click');
  jQuery('.' + dependingvar_).hide();
  lastdepend = dependingvar_;
} else {
  jQuery('.' + lastdepend).show();
}
```

Comment: Of course, perfect! I must've just gone blind from working on this so long. Thanks a lot! I never noticed it was running itself..

Comment: It's a good reminder of why the distinction between `undefined` and `null` is important. You would likely have noticed that the value wasn't `undefined`, but `null` in line 4.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `dependingvar` outside the function, so it is in global scope. Every change you make by other function-calls (in this case by calling `children('.cdesign-toggle').first().trigger('click');` will also be effective within your current scope.

This code will demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/r87b1f9k/1/

Move the definition inside the function (commented out in the demo), so other calls to `click` wont alter the same `dependingvar`.